# What is the difference between ros::NodeHandle nh("") and just ros::NodeHandle nh?

Tags: ros, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that `ros::NodeHandle nh("~")` is a private namespace and that `ros::NodeHandle nh("/")` is the global namespace but what exactly is the difference between `ros::NodeHandle nh("")` and `ros::NodeHandle nh`, are they the same thing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381198/what-is-the-difference-between-ros::nodehandle-nh(%22%22)-and-just-ros::nodehandle-nh?/) by [ParkerRobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/56923/parkerrobert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could easily answer this for yourself by looking at the c++ constructor in `/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h`.

The answer is: Yes, `nh` and `nh("")` construct the identical object.

To help other people who need to read your code, you should use the first version.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ParkerRobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/56923/parkerrobert/) on 2021-06-27**:
That was a clear answer, the constructor is NodeHandle(const std::string& ns = std::string(), const M_string& remappings = M_string()) in `/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h`, as you said. Leaving it empty will result in ns = std::string() and using nh("") would also result in an empty string. So effectively they are both the same